# What is the meaning of “what has come” in the given context?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I have listened to the song "Goodbye" by Avril Lavigne, where I noticed the phrase **what has come**.

> Goodbye, goodbye, goodbye my love
>
> I can't hide, can't hide, can't hide **what has come**

What is the actual meaning of the given sentence in this context?

Comment: Can you give us the context in which the sentence appears?

Comment: I think it means "What has happened".

Comment: @GreatCrosby the complete sentence is "Goodbye, goodbye, goodbye my love
I can't hide, can't hide, can't hide what has come
"

Comment: Thank you. I don't feel 100% confident but think, like Khan, it means what has happened. And it's love that has happened.

Answer (score 1):

In that context, it means "what has happened".

The use of the verb "to come", in the absence of other modifiers, also implies that what has happened had an influence on the first person, singular or plural (i.e. **to me** or **to us**).